# AWS EC2 Assuming cron creating some random empty files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I am assuming cron keep creating random empty files in my root directory with name `users-recall?type=cron.***` - * (some random numbers could be with dots like 111.01). And it has only 2 jobs in it.

```
*/1 * * * * cd /var/www/html/*** && php script.php > /dev/null 2>&1
0 */1 * * * wget -q -t 1 https://domain/users-recall?type=cron > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I tried to search it but couldn't find it. It creates it daily or so. Not creating it every minute. I am not sure what else could create this files. I have just AWS EC2 Linux server with nothing additional installed except standart tools.

Answer (score 1):

Sending the STDOUT/STDERR output of `wget` to /dev/null is not sufficient if you don't want a file to be created.

Modify your command by adding `-O -`.

```
... type=cron -O - > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The `-O` option (uppercase letter O) is the short form for `--output-document`, and the next `-` means to use STDOUT instead of creating a file on disk from the response.  By default, wget creates a file, and appends a counter to the end if the file already exists.  Since you are discarding STDOUT with `> /dev/null`, this will do what you intend -- make a web request, and discard the output.

Answer (score 0):

these files are getting created by ur second cronjob for sure. You can comment that job and see that those files will stop getting created.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try enclosing the URL in single quote?

```
0 */1 * * * wget -q -t 1 'https://domain/users-recall?type=cron' > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The character `?` may get interpreted by shell depending on the SHELL variable of the cronfile.